# rich:fileUpload randomly fails with "Transfer failed" error

Tags: jsf, file-upload, richfaces

I am using `<rich:fileUpload>` of RichFaces 3.3.3 Final. When I upload some Excel files in Chrome browser, then it sometimes shows the "Transfer failed" error message as in below screenshot:

Sample Code,

```
<rich:fileUpload id="fileUpload" addControlLabel="#{bundle.browse}"
                 allowFlash="#{not TestFileUpload.allow}"
                 fileUploadListener="#{TestFileUpload.fileUploadListener}"
                 maxFilesQuantity="10"  
                 autoclear="false"
                 listHeight="135px;"
                 uploadControlLabel="#{bundle.upload}"
                 progressLabel="#{bundle.progress}"
                 sizeErrorLabel="#{bundle.sizeError}"
                 noDuplicate="true" 
                 style="width: 100%; height: 135px;">

    <a4j:support event="onuploadcomplete" 
                 onbeforedomupdate=""
                 action="#{TestFileUpload.validateExcel}" 
                 reRender="validationDetailPanelId, messageId"
                 focus="cancelId"/>
</rich:fileUpload>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!--Configuration for Facelets-->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.jsp</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>
            facelets.RECREATE_VALUE_EXPRESSION_ON_BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE
        </param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
        <param-value>*.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.verifyObjects</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.validateXml</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.COMPRESS_SCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
        <param-value>all</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
        <param-value>all</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.SKIN</param-name>
        <param-value>Wine</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
        <param-value>enable</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/test/faces-config.xml
    </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
        <filter-name>Ajax4jsf</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>enable-cache</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>createTempFiles</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>maxRequestSize</param-name>
            <param-value>1048576</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>SFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.test.SFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <listener>
        <display-name>SLCListener</display-name>
        <listener-class>com.test.SLCListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- End of Rich Faces and A4JSF -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Custom Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.test.CFServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>error</param-name>
            <param-value>/faces/pages/errorPage.jsp</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ASServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.test.ASServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PASRServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.test.PASRServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LOServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.test.LOServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>DException</param-name>
            <param-value>/faces/pages/dException.jsp</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FDServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.test.FDServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <!--OverRiding FacesServlet Start-->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Custom Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Custom Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!--Filter for ajaxrequest and Custom Faces Servlet-->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Ajax4jsf</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Custom Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SSEFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Custom Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!--End-->

    <!-- Filter for Commons File Upload -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Extensions Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
            <param-value>20m</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Extensions Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Custom Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- End of commons file upload filter -->
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/faces/pages/error/errorPage.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
  </web-app>
```

[image]

The file is also not being uploaded to the server. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: This looks more a like a server error, did you check the logs?

Comment: @Makhiel not able to get the server log.

Comment: Does it happen randomly or it is not able to upload any file ?

Comment: @Apurv it happens randomly.

Comment: Do the filenames contain spaces? There is [a bug in the RF 3.X upload control](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12656).

Comment: @cheffe Thanks for your suggestion, but we already controlled that problem.

Comment: Can you try to embed the [<a4j:log />](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_log.html) in the page? Probably that gives more informations about what is going on.

Comment: Yes we use <a4j:log/>, but it will not show anything based on that.

Comment: It's possible this is moot now, Chrome update (36.0.1985.125 m) breaks this component more generally, viewable on the live demo site: https://community.jboss.org/message/881574

Comment: Yes i accept, but this happened in IE9 also.

Comment: Can you some code, like your xhtml, or at least, your rich:fileUpload tag.

Comment: Can you post your web.xml file?

Comment: I read in a thread once that the order of the servlets and filters on web xml may cause some strange behaviors with the components. Try to put all servlets after the filter mappings and turn this ` <filter-name>Ajax4jsf</filter-name>` the last of the filters. And try to see what happens. I'm going to sleep now. It is late here. Tomorrow I will came back and see what turns out.

Comment: same problem for me also give me a idea to solve

Comment: i am using 3.3.3 version richfaces will it makes problem for modern browser

Comment: You are using 3.3.4 final right...

Comment: @ArunPrasath i think it may be ajax issue you can find issue from your log file of a4j:log and ask Sixface he will guide you.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem since one of the lastest update of Chrome.
Chrome version : 36

The fileUploadListener method in the bean is called twice when you click on the upload button.
The debug mode reveals that The second time, the file is lost.

I bypassed the problem like that :

```
public void fileUploadListener(UploadEvent event) {

    if(!event.getUploadItem().getFileName().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        //code here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First make your bean session scope then in web.xml change boolean attribute of createTempFiles to false instead of true just as below:

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>createTempFiles</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
```